# Rails scope on association of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

quick question. 
I'm trying to build a scope without success. I have these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :store, required: true
has_many :visits
has_one :company, through: :store

end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, required: true
  has_many :users, dependent: :nullify
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :stores
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**edit**

Now I need to draw some chart using Chartkick Gem and the best way is to start from the Visit model.

I'm using

```
Visit.group_by_day("started_at", range: 3.month.ago.midnight..Date.today.midnight, format: "%b %-e").order("day asc").count
```

If I need all the visits, but now I need to filter also the visits for company and for store.

I cannot understand how can I get all the visits from users that belong to a specific store or to a specific company.

The simplest way is:

```
Visit.where("user_id IN (?)", company.users.ids)
```

It works, but I prefear to write a better scope and the one I write doesn't work.

```
  class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :user_by_store, ->(store_id) {
    joins(:user).where('user.store_id' => store_id) 
  }
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be able to do:

```
scope :by_company, -> (company) { joins(:company).where(companies: {id: company}) }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add 'user.store_id' in the method `where` you are using SQL. The name of the table is usually **plural** according to Rails standards.

The only thing that you needed to fix in your code is to change `user` -> `users`

```
scope :user_by_store, ->(store_id) {
  joins(:user).where('users.store_id' => store_id) 
}
```

And of course, for filtering by company you can use @oreoluwa's answer but fix the same mistake in the name of the table.

```
scope :by_company, -> (company) { joins(:company).where(companies: {id: company}) }
```